# C# - Lock directory until all files get copied into it

Tags: c#

At particular location, directory with files inside it gets created. At that location another software continuously checks for new directory and then process that directory immediately.

Now, The problem is,

When I want to copy files to that location, I first create directory, and then copy all the files inside it. But as soon as directory gets created, the processing software process that directory and deletes it. And my copy function raise an exception.

```
if (!Directory.Exists(DestinationPath))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(DestinationPath);
CopyFilesInDirectory();//Throw exception as directory created above processed by another software and deleted.
```

What I want to do is, stop the parent directory from getting processed by another software until my copying of files gets completed.

Comment: Maybe create a user on the fly, backup the current security settings on the folder, only allow the user to access it, then after copying, restore the settings?

Comment: Why not create the directory outside the scope of the monitoring tool, and then fill it with stuff, and when done, move the directory to its final location.

Comment: Is the other software modifiable/configurable? If so, could it be told to filter out particular directory names?

Comment: @RaymondChen Its good suggestion. But the problem in it that there may be thousand of files on server. So copying the content twice is costly here.

Comment: @ArpitGupta - if the "outside scope" directory and the monitored directory are on the same *volume*, I believe the move should just be metadata updates - no second copy. However, be wary, because I can't seem to find documentation that states this to be so (but have you ever noticed the difference in speed between moving directories around on one drive vs moving directories between separate drives?)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever "[the MoveFile function will fail on directory moves when the destination is on a different volume](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-movefile)".

Answer (score 1):

If you have a small window of opportunity, you can block the other software from deleting the directory by keeping a file open in it, like

```
if (!Directory.Exists(DestinationPath))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(DestinationPath);
using(var lockFile = File.Open(Path.Combine(DestinationPath, "_lock"))
{
   CopyFilesInDirectory();
}
```

If the other software may delete the directory after the second and third line, you will need to try again until you get the lock file open.

The cleaner way would be to modify the other software, of course.

Comment: I think I am not getting luck in it. I also tried to create temp text file stream and kept it open throughout but it also didn't work. Also Not getting any way to modify the other software.